# how can I change specific menu item text colour? background changing but text colour not changing?

Tags: jquery, css

I have used following CSS codes in order to change specific menu item background and text color in an wordpress site. After applying the code, Background color has been changed but text color not changing. Can anyone help me please to make it work. My CSS codes are as follows which I have used (please note that same code I have used in different website that worked):

```
/*RESERVATION MENUBAR*/
.reserve-menu {
    background-color: #dd0000;
    color: #fff;
    }

.reserve-menu:hover,
.reserve-menu:focus,
.reserve-menu:active {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #fff; !important;
    }
```

**I have applied above code in this site. please see there is a Menu called "RESERVATION": https://www.bombaydininghenley.co.uk/**

Comment: In `color: #fff; !important;`, remove the semi-colon in the middle... --> `color: #fff !important;`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette,
Thank you for your reply. I have done this but didn't work. I tried also by removing important. Still remained same. :(

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have resolved this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just your selector not enough specificity
It should be

```
#main-menu ul li a:hover
```

or

```
.reserve-menu a:hover
```

The current selector you're using to set color is `#main-menu ul li a`
The element is being affected by css file `asian.css` and its selector is `.dark a:hover`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I applied both but it didn't work. Yes you are right it is default by theme but I wanted to change by force and expected should work. Unfortunately, none worked. :(

#main-menu ul li a:hover 
.reserve-menu a:hover

Comment: try this one `#main-menu ul li .reserve-menu a:hover { color: #FFF; }`
I think it should work, otherwise you may set the this line of css somewhere before other rules. Which file do you added to?

Comment: I applied this as well, unfortunately it didn't work too  :(

Comment: I applied on your site & it works well. Not sure what did you do though.

Comment: Let me give send you that what I have written:

/*RESERVATION MENU BAR*/
.reserve-menu {
    background-color: #dd0000;
    color: #fff;
    }
    
#main-menu ul li .reserve-menu a:hover 
.reserve-menu:focus,
.reserve-menu:active {
    background-color: #262626;
    color: #fff;
 border: 2px solid #dd0000;
 }

Comment: You need to add a , after a:hover

Comment: Thank you. I am stupid, I missed the stupid "a" to write after .reserve-menu in the first paragraph and I have been concentrating second paragraph. I have been changing everything but I didn't notice this. I really appreciate for your support. I wouldn't notice until @James Hector Ayensu noticed this. 

Thank you once again

Comment: I have one more issue, after applying border on hover onto the same menu item, it is keep pushing other menu item left. I would be grateful if you can give me any suggestion please. Thank you

Comment: border Issue has been solved as well. I used "outline". Thank you for your help.

Comment: @SAYEDRAHMAN ok, that's great. I was investigating the border method :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the anchor tag for the color to work. Try something like this

```
 .reserve-menu a{
     color: #000;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am stupid, I missed the stupid "a" to write after .reserve-menu. I have been changing everything but I didn't notice this. I really appreciate.

Comment: Your welcome! Make sure you mark an answer as solved so people know.

Comment: I have one more issue, after applying border on hover onto the same menu item, it is keep pushing other menu item left. For border on hover I have used this code:  border: 2px solid #dd0000; I would be grateful if you can give me any suggestion please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Style.css file:

```
.reserve-menu a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

This will keep it as #fff the entire time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this as well but it didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: @SAYED RAHMAN Where exactly are you placing this? I haven't used wordpress in a while but I might catch something.

Comment: @SAYEDRAHMAN I don't know exactly how wordpress allows you to choose your style link tags, but try to reorder them so that it calls custom_theme.css first then style.css. Also are you clearing cache so it shows on the website?